# Validate a form field with a php function and jquery ajax

Tags: php, forms, validation, jquery

I'm using wordpress and I have a form that I need to validate. I have an input field to check to make sure it's a valid youtube url. 
I found this nifty little method using jquery..

```
  $("input#video_url").change(function (){
    var matches = $(this).val().match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/);
    if (matches) {
      $(".video-validation").append("<span>Valid</span>");
     } else {
      $(".video-validation").append("<span>This is not a valid youtube url</span>");
     }
  });
```

But then I read that validation like this needs to be done with php, so that it can't be changed on the client-side.

I've been looking for some type of clear tutorial on this but can't find one. So my question is:

How can I turn this validation of the url into a php function in my functions.php and then use that in combination with jquery to do ajax validation before the form can be processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a ajax post wit the link:

```
$.post('validate.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

And do the same think in your **validate.php** file something like this:

`validate.php`

```
$result = preg_match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/);
if ( $result ) {
  die( '<span>Valid</span>' );
} else {
  die( '<span>This is not a valid youtube url</span>');
}
```

You end code might look like this:

```
$("input#video_url").change(function (){
  $.post('validate.php', function(data) {
    $('.video-validation').html(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy this little regexp:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9\-_\|]{11})/i', $gyoutube, $matches))
{
    $error = "This ain't a Youtube video";
}
```

Also, PHP validation is done **after**, not before the form has been submitted.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can ajax call it `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: yes, but it's useless. For the client site, in this case, there is no reason you would AJAX it instead of using JS validation. Both can be hacked just as easy.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link for the tutorial - http://www.krio.me/how-to-validate-a-url-php/

you can also use the filter_var() function - filter_var('test.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)